# Scala Spark DataFrame.selectExpr throws excepton org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'name' given input columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame (df) that I need to add some transformed columns into it.  The original columns are "name, address" and the transformed columns are substr of name as subName and substr of address of subAdd.  I combined these two sets of column together and pass the entire list to:

```
     df.selectExpr(allColumnsList)
```

However I got the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'name' given input columns
```

If I removed the "name" column from the schema, then the same exception was thrown on "address" column.  I wonder if this is because I changed the original DataFrame (df) by adding the transformed columns to it.  Anyone know why I am getting the exception ?

Comment: You're going to have to show more than this -- like, do `df.printSchema` and show the results; show us what `allColumnsList` looks like, etc.

Comment: I am running my program on SpringXD framework, so i guess I can't use df.printSchema() as it will be printed on the console.  so, Can I use df.schema.mkString() ?